# Redirect from directory to other server works for http but not for https

Tags: https, apache2, httpd.conf

I have problem with HTTPD redirection. I need to redirect directory /as/ to another host, with all parameters that are passed trough.
I have below configuration in conf file, and it only works for HTTP protocol, but does not for HTTPS. What I am missing here?

```
 <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
      LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        RewriteEngine on
        ServerName xxx:443
        ServerAlias xxx:443
        RedirectMatch "^/as/(.*)$" "https://xxx/as/$1"
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RedirectMatch "^/as/(.*)$" "https://xxx/as/$1"
</VirtualHost>
```

On HTTPS I am getting status 200 instead of 302.

Comment: Please be more specific about the `does not work part`. What's the error message you get?

Comment: If you are getting a 200 response there is a different virtualhost in your config that apache prefers to use.

Comment: Does this question apply: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819390/apache-loads-mod-ssl-but-ifmodule-mod-ssl-c-ignored-in-my-vhosts - Seems to me it's ignoring what in the <IfModule> try it without the <IfModule> to troubleshoot.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider You were right, previous virtualhost took priority over the one created here, when I included it in previous https host, it worked just fine.

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting a 200 response there is a different `<VirtualHost>` section somewhere in your config that Apache prefers over this one.